# How to play notification sound using onesignal notification via REST API?

Tags: php, api, rest, postman, onesignal

I have tried a lot of things on like created channel mode, added sound in res/raw directory it works well with when we send notification directly from onesignal dashboard but I'm not able to figure out how can I send it through API. I refered onesignals official documentation and see something android_channel_id and also set it in API [API Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJHjZ.png)

Please help me if anyone knows how to enable sound via API by the way the notification is working well but can't able to play sound.

Comment: Do you have an update? I have the same issue, through the `OneSignal Dashboard` , a sound can be sent easily, but through `Postman`, i can not find a way...